# Prevent applications from changing audio input gain

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, microphone

I have a USB mixer that is recognized by Windows as a USB microphone (as per the manufacturer's instructions). My microphone and other inputs are plugged into this mixer. Every once in a while when I am not talking the input level for the device shoots up. This is being caused by Google Chrome (it seems to usually happen when GMail or a Hangout is open).

Either way, how can I prevent applications from changing the input level? This is extremely annoying and sometimes in the middle of a VOIP phone call the level will shoot up causing distortion and making it quite unpleasant for the people on the other end of the call?

Comment: IMO you should Uninstall Chrome and Hangouts to ensure you're assumption is correct first.

Comment: Well I really don't want ANY applications having the ability to modify the gain. I'd like to lock this setting, regardless of what may be changing it. But I did kill all Chrome processes and everything seemed fine at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this great little utility called "VolumeLock" by "Actual Solutions" that locks the volumes of specified audio devices. It comes with a free 14-day trial. After downloading it and trying it for about 30 seconds, I purchased it ($14.95).

It can be downloaded at http://www.actualsolution.com/volume-lock/

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Right Click on the Audio Icon in the bottom right of the taskbar. Select "Recording Devices", then right click on the Microphone you are using and select Properties. Select the Advanced Tab, and uncheck "Allow Applications to take exclusive control of this device" and "Give exclusive mode applications priority". Let me know if that works.

Comment: Nope. I had already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as comment but donot have enough reputation anyways . The behavior you see is a characteristic of Audio level specified by [WebRTC Audio Codec and Processing Requirements draft-ietf-rtcweb-audio-07](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-audio-07)

> It states that If the client has control over the entire audio capture
> path, as is typically the case for a regular phone, then it is
> RECOMMENDED that the gain be adjusted in such a way that active speech
> have a level of 2600 (-19 dBm0) for an average speaker.  If the client
> does not have control over the entire audio capture, as is typically
> the case for a software client, then the client SHOULD use automatic
> gain control (AGC) to dynamically adjust the level to 2600 (-19 dBm0)
> +/- 6 dB.  For music or desktop sharing applications, the level SHOULD NOT be automatically adjusted and the client SHOULD allow the user to
> set the gain manually.

Hence the best you can do if to install third party software to forcefully curb this or shut down webrtc based applications in such cases